# Programatically setting a Model's Fields in Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have a model `Food`

```py
class Food(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    toppings = models.TextField()
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(FoodScheme, models.CASCADE)
```

And I want to have another class, a `FoodScheme` which describes which of the fields must be set in a specific `Food` class.

```py
class FoodScheme(models.Model):
    scheme_name = models.TextField()
    requires_description = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    requires_toppings = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But instead of hard coding this, I want to programmatically set these fields up, so any change in Food will change the FoodScheme class too.

An example implementation (that doesn't work, for several reasons, but I think gets my point across):

```py
class FoodScheme(models.Model):
    scheme_name = models.TextField()
    for f in Food.get_fields():
        setattr(self, f"requires_{f.name}", models.BooleanField(default=False))
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with migrations for such constructions

Comment: Maybe you'll be interested in the library `django dynamic models` : https://github.com/rvinzent/django-dynamic-models

Comment: What exact benefit is of your schema that you cannot get just by checking if field is required in Food model

Comment: the best suggestion is to go with mongodb

Comment: @iklinac It would allow you to specify several different classes of food and create new classes without changing any code

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by iklinac, the easiest way to get this to work is using a `JSONField`. This allows the content to be dynamic.

Here's an example `GenericScheme`:

```py
class GenericScheme(models.Model):

    scheme_name = models.TextField(default="Unnamed Scheme")
    scheme_json = models.JSONField(default=dict)

    model = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.scheme_json = {}
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.model is None:
            return
        for f in self.model._meta.get_fields():
            if f.name not in self.scheme_json:
                self.scheme_json[f.name] = False
```